# How to place widgets on base of another widget's position?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to place my widgets dynamically. If I change the position of one widget all other widgets should be moved aswell.

I tried something like this, but "Test" is not displayed correctly as I want. It is on the left of my entry widget, but I want it + 20px added to TypEntry.

```py
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=300)
canvas.pack()

TypEntry = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
TypEntry.pack()
TypEntry.place(x=xPosForHeader+50, y=yPosForHeader)

ArtikelLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Test")
ArtikelLabel.pack()
ArtikelLabel.place(x=TypEntry.winfo_x()+20, y=yPosForHeader)
```

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Tkinter provides several ways to place widgets relative to each other. The solution depends on lot on _exactly_ the sort of layout that you want.

Comment: Calling both `.pack()` and `.place()` on the same widget is pointless.  And widget information methods like `.winfo_x()` do not return valid results immediately after creating a widget, you have to call `.update_idletasks()` (or otherwise perform at least one iteration of the mainloop) for them to actually work.

Comment: That makes sense. I thought that pack is the geometry manager I wanted to use and place is something like a function of it after I create the object with .pack().

Answer (score 5):

It's a little unclear exactly what you're asking, because tkinter provides several ways to place widgets relative to other widgets.

However, if you literally have no constraints other than one widget be placed relative to another, the simplest solution is `place`. In my experience `place` is almost never the right solution except in very rare circumstances since you have to do a lot more of the work yourself.

If you read the documentation for `place` you'll see that there are options specifically for relative placement. These options include `relx`, `rely`, `relwidth` and `relheight`.

Using your code, it would look like this:

```
ArtikelLabel.place(in_=TypEntry, relx=1.0, x=20, rely=0)
```

In this example the options have the following effect:

- **in_** specifies the widget that this widget is relative to
- **relx** is a floating point value where 0 means the left edge of the other widget, and 1.0 means the right edge. By using `1.0`, we are saying that the want the label to be positioned relative to the far right edge of the entry widget.
- **x** is an absolute number. When used in combination with with `relx`, the values are summed. Thus `relx=1.0, x=20` means 20 pixels to the right of the right edge
- **rely** specifies that the widget is to be aligned to the top edge of the widget.

Comment: I have got a lot of widgets and there will be plenty more, but as it is a specification / welcome I just simplified my code to. So I wanted to work with pack. Thanks for your answer, but I dont think that this is my solution here.

Comment: @ebug38: if this doesn't answer your question, you should rewrite the question to be more clear. As written, this does exactly what was asked -- it places a widget relative to another.

Comment: Sorry my bad. As I mentioned in the comment I did not realize that I have used 2 geometry managers. I have to rewrite my code instead :P. Maybe I will find a solution for the pack() manager myself. Thanks for your help. Your solution is legit.